# How to print line number specific element inside complex child elements using python

Tags: python, xml, lxml

Example of my XML1 consists of format of Equal element :

```
<Operator>
    <Equal>
        <Data>A1</Data>
        <Data>2</Data>
    </Equal>
    <Equal>
        <Integer>A2</Integer>
        <Data>2</Data>
    </Equal>
    <Equal>
        <Integer>A3</Integer>
        <Integer>2</Integer>
    </Equal>
</Operator>
```

And the following code runs fine for finding 'equal' elements if there are not many child element

```
doc = etree.parse('C:/Python/Sample.xml')
doc2 = etree.parse('C:/Python/Project.xml')
values = [e.xpath('.//*[2]')[0].text for e in doc.xpath('.//Equal')]

for service in doc2.xpath('//Sub_Function_1//Data[Label and .//Equal//*[2]]'):
    value = service.xpath('.//Equal//*[2]')
    if value[0].text in values:
        print(service.xpath('.//Label/text()')[0], f"lineno: {value[0].sourceline}")
```

small example of XML2 is as follows where its not able to match 'equal' in all cases :

```
<File>
    <Sub_Function_1>
        <Messages>
            <Setting>
                <Data>
                    <Label>Setting_1</Label>
                    <Bit_count>8</Bit_count>
                    <Value>
                        <Default_value_if_undefined>
                            <Value>
                                <!---->
                                <Value_on_boolean>
                                    <And>
                                        <Equal>
                                            <Integer>area_1</Integer>
                                            <Data>2</Data>
                                        </Equal>
                                    </And>
                                </Value_on_boolean>
                            </Value>
                            <Default_value>
                                <Integer>0</Integer>
                            </Default_value>
                        </Default_value_if_undefined>
                    </Value>
                </Data>
                <Data>
                    <Label>Setting_2</Label>
                    <Bit_count>1</Bit_count>
                    <Value>
                        <Value_on_condition>
                            <Case>
                                <Value>
                                    <Integer>1</Integer>
                                </Value>
                                <Condition>
                                    <And>
                                        <Equal>
                                            <Integer>0</Integer>
                                            <Integer>0</Integer>
                                        </Equal>
                                        <Equal>
                                            <Data>area_2</Data>
                                            <Integer>0</Integer>
                                        </Equal>
                                    </And>
                                </Condition>
                            </Case>
                            <Case>
                                <Value>
                                    <Integer>2</Integer>
                                </Value>
                                <Condition>
                                    <And>
                                        <Equal>
                                            <Data>area_3</Data>
                                            <Integer>1</Integer>
                                        </Equal>
                                        <Equal>
                                            <Integer>area_4</Integer>
                                            <Data>0</Data>
                                        </Equal>
                                    </And>
                                </Condition>
                            </Case>
                            <Case>
                                <Value>
                                    <Integer>3</Integer>
                                </Value>
                                <Condition/>
                            </Case>
                        </Value_on_condition>
                    </Value>
                </Data>
            </Setting>
        </Messages>
    </Sub_Function_1>
</File>
```

Running the above code give results as:

```
Setting_1 lineno: 18
```

But its not able to find 'equal' inside 'value on condition' as there are many cases inside it
so line number 39 and 60 its not printing

Always grateful for any help.

Comment: It could be because `//*[2]` is `<Integer>0</Integer>` and there's no `0` on `values`. Try adding `else: print("**** missing" + service.xpath('.//Label/text()')[0], f"lineno: {value[0].sourceline}")` to the if-else

Comment: @LMC yes its working and printing line no. 41
but for some reason its not able to search another case(2) inside 'value on condition' and printing line 62

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is taking only the first `Equal` found so it fails when there are 2 or more

```
for service in doc.xpath('//Sub_Function_1//Data[Label and .//Equal[(*[1][self::Data] and *[2][self::Data]) or *[1][self::Integer]]]'):
     eqs = service.xpath('.//Equal[(*[1][self::Data] and *[2][self::Data]) or *[1][self::Integer]]/*[2]')
     for e in eqs:
         print(service.xpath('.//Label/text()')[0], f"lineno: {e.sourceline}")
```

Result

```
Setting_1 lineno: 16
Setting_2 lineno: 40
Setting_2 lineno: 61
```

Comment: For loop is printing all "equal" line no.
`Setting_2 lineno: 44
Setting_2 lineno: 57`

these are not required to print as this 'equal' is not present in XML1

Comment: why its printing all line numbers wherever 'equal' is present
when here its matching text from XML1
`values = [e.xpath('.//*[2]')[0].text for e in doc.xpath('.//Equal')]`

Comment: It's because they way I tested with an static : `values = [ '0','1','2','2' ]`

Comment: so, isn't there a way where values can be used to comapare and then store it and matches its value in another xml before printing

Comment: The rest of your code should be the same. I just added the loop to check every element found. Just used an static comparison list. This is working `values = [e.xpath('.//*[2]')[0].text for e in doc.xpath('.//Equal')]`. Use it.

Comment: yes, I have
and i am really trying get output as this
`Setting_1 lineno: 17
Setting_2 lineno: 41
Setting_2 lineno: 62`
but using for loop is printing all lines of equal and using only if else is stopping at first counter and printing only two lines 17 and 41
not understanding what is missing

Comment: There's something wrong in your specs. From xml1 `values = [ '2','2','2' ]` but `//Equals//*[2]` at line 40 is `<Integer>0</Integer>` so it will never be found in `values`. Also, you expect to find line 40 but not line 44 it seems but both match the criteria.

Comment: In XML1 <Integer>2</Integer> i have just written as an example i actually just wanted to match the sequence of child elements i.e 1)equal->data->data 2)equal->integer->data 3)equal->integer->integer
line 40 and line 44 is not same as per my task as in line 44 the sequence is equal->data->integer which is not required

Comment: I actually didn't want it to be dependent on value 2 as it can be anything

Comment: Changed the answer. Hope it helps. Add the if-else at your convinience

Comment: Equal[(*[1][self::Data] and *[2][self::Data]) or *[1][self::Integer]]/*[2]' I wanted to understand this part as I am trying to add more conditions to 'equal' in XML1 for example if I add <Equal> <Data>A1</Data> </Equal> then adding this is not working //Equal[((*[1][self::Data] and *[2][self::Data] ) or *[1][self::Integer]) or *[2][self::Data]]/*[2]

Comment: `/*[2]` means there's a second child which is not present in your addition. The condition for that could be `(*[1][self::Data] and not(*[2]))`

Comment: this is running fine when 'value' has only one condition
`[((*[1][self::Data] and *[2][self::Data]) or *[1][self::Integer]) or *[1][self::Data]]/*[1][self::Data]`
but on <Value_on_condition>(example given in XML2) when it has multiple 'equal' to check with conditions its printing lines even when both [1]data and [2]integer are there inside 'equal' even though here this condition is there *[1][self::Integer].
wherever it encounters first 'Equal->Data' in <Value_on_condition> it will print.
how to find whether only one child element is there even on '<Value_on_condition>'

Comment: As I said in my previous comment: /*[2] means there's a second child which is not present in your addition. The condition for that could be (*[1][self::Data] and not(*[2]))

Comment: Now if i again want to print line for the same conditions but there is no Label present in XML
then i have used this code
`for service in doc2.xpath('//File//Data[.//Equal[(*[1][self::Data] and *[2][self::Data]) or *[1][self::Integer]]]'):
`
`print(service.xpath('.//File/text()')[0], f"lineno: {e.sourceline}")`
where i have just removed the Label from code
but its not printing any line no.
can you please correct me

Comment: As it is it must be throwing error. Where's `e` defined? Seems you missed 2 lines from my answer.

Comment: i didnt miss it
`for service in doc2.xpath('//File//Data[.//Equal[(*[1][self::Data] and *[2][self::Data]) or *[1][self::Integer]]]'):
    eqs = service.xpath('.//Equal[(*[1][self::Data] and *[2][self::Data]) or *[1][self::Integer]]/*[2]')
    for e in eqs:
      print(service.xpath('.//File/text()')[0], f"lineno: {e.sourceline}")

`
so the code is exact as you mentioned just removed label from it

Comment: //File/text() is empty in your sample. You need to learn XPath and test xpath expressions outside your code or with an smaller script. Also, read about how to debug python. You can use `xmllint --xpath 'some xpath'  file.xml` on Linux/MacOS command line.

Comment: okay,
removed text portion so now its running
`for service in doc2.xpath('//File[.//Equal[(*[1][self::Data] and *[2][self::Data]) or *[1][self::Integer]]]'):
`
.....
`print(e.tag, e.sourceline)`